# Opengl camera and render problems

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm acutally trying open gl and have some questions: 
I actually have this code:

```
    #include <freeglut.h>
    #include <glut.h> 
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;

    char presse;
    int anglex=-45, angley=45, x, y, xold, yold;

    /* Prototype des fonctions (function prototypes) */
    void affichage();
    void clavier(unsigned char touche, int x, int y);
    void reshape(int x, int y);
    void idle();
    void mouse(int bouton, int etat, int x, int y);
    void mousemotion(int x, int y);


    const GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat light_position[] = { 1, 2, 1, 1 };

    const GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    const GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0f };

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    /* initialisation de glut et creation
    de la fenetre (glut initialization and window creation) */
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("cube");

    /* Initialisation d'OpenGL (OpenGL initialisation) */
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPointSize(2.0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    // Active le test de profondeur
(activate depth testing)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);  // Active l'éclairage
(activate lighting)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);    // Allume la lumière n°1
(turn on light no. 1)
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, high_shininess);

    /* enregistrement des fonctions de rappel (register callbacks) */
    glutDisplayFunc(affichage);
    glutKeyboardFunc(clavier);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(mousemotion);

    /* Entree dans la boucle principale glut (entry of the main glut loop) */
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
    }


    double a = 0;
    int LightPos[4] = { -1, 4, -1, 1 };
    int MatSpec[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    void affichage()
    {   
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    a = +1;


    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef(angley, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(anglex, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
        if (k == 0){
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
            glEnd();
        }
        else {
            if (k > 0){
                        glBegin(GL_LINES);
                            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0);
                            glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 0);
                            glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 0.5);
                        glEnd();

                    }
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0);
                glVertex3f(k, 0, 0);
                glVertex3f(k, 0, 0.5);
            glEnd();


        }

        }


    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
        if (k == 0){
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
                glVertex3f(0, 5, 0);
            glEnd();
        }
        else {
            if (k >0){
                GLfloat n = k / 2;
                glBegin(GL_LINES);
                    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0);
                    glVertex3f(0, 0.5, 0);
                    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0);
                glEnd();
            }
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0);
                glVertex3f(0, k, 0);
                glVertex3f(0.5, k, 0);
            glEnd();


        }
    }


    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
        if (k == 0){
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.6, 1.0);
            glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            glVertex3f(0, 0, 5);
            glEnd();
        }
        else {
            if (k >0){
                GLfloat n = k / 2;
                glBegin(GL_LINES);
                glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                glVertex3f(0, 0, 0.5);
                glVertex3f(0, 0.5, 0.5);
                glEnd();
            }
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 10);
            glVertex3f(0, 0, k);
            glVertex3f(0, 0.5, k);
            glEnd();


        }
    }



    // Par terre scene
(ground scene)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3d(0,-0.1,0);
    glVertex3d(5, -0.1, 0);
    glVertex3d(5, -0.1, 5);
    glVertex3d(0, -0.1, 5);

        glEnd();



        glFlush();

       glutSwapBuffers();
       }

    void clavier(unsigned char touche, int x, int y)
    {
    switch (touche)
    {


    case 'o': /* eteindre la lumiere (turn off the light) */
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        //std::cout << "lumiere eteinte";

        break;
    case 'a': /* eteindre la lumiere (turn off the light) */
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'p': /* affichage du carre plein (normal fill mode, interior of the polygon is filled) */
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'f': /* affichage en mode fil de fer (draw polygon edges as lines) */
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 's': /* Affichage en mode sommets seuls (draw polygon vertices as points) */
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POINT);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'd':
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'D':
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'q': /*la touche 'q' permet de quitter le programme (the key 'q' exits the program) */
        exit(0);
     }
     }

     void reshape(int x, int y)
    {
    if (x<y)
        glViewport(0, (y - x) / 2, x, x);
    else
        glViewport((x - y) / 2, 0, y, y);
    }

    void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
    {
    /* si on appuie sur le bouton gauche (if you press the left button) */
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        presse = 1; /* le booleen presse passe a 1 (vrai) (the boolean presse is set to 1 (true)) */
        xold = x; /* on sauvegarde la position de la souris (save the position of the mouse) */
        yold = y;
    }
    /* si on relache le bouton gauche (if you release the left button) */
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP)
        presse = 0; /* le booleen presse passe a 0 (faux) (the boolean presse is set to 0 (false)) */
    }

    void mousemotion(int x, int y)
    {
    if (presse) /* si le bouton gauche est presse (if the left button is pressed) */
    {
        /* on modifie les angles de rotation de l'objet
        en fonction de la position actuelle de la souris et de la derniere
        position sauvegardee (modify the rotation angles of the object
depending on the current position of the mouse and the last
saved position) */
        anglex = anglex + (x - xold);
        angley = angley + (y - yold);
        glutPostRedisplay(); 
    }

    xold = x; 
    yold = y;
    }
```

But I can't manage the scene to just draw the x,y and z axis to it's full extend. The rendered object are "cut" in the screen. How can I first draw them entirely and then move the camera backwards? I happily already managed the move the camera a bit etc.. but it's still freaking complicated...

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting up any specific projection matrix, so you will get the default of an identity matrix. This means that the *viewing volume* will range from -1 to 1 along all three axis. Hence, objects are cut if they reach outside of this volume.

Comment: well I tried implementing  glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)1000,(GLsizei)1000);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glFrustum(-3.0, 3.0, -5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); but it didn't help in any way...

Comment: I added this in the reshape part

Comment: @nightslit: The frustum you specified doesn't make any sense: using 1.0 both for `near` and `far` will not work, this would create a viewing "volume" without any volume at all, so cut _everything_.

Comment: Well I changed the glFrustum to glFrustum(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0); to add more depth but it doesn't look like anything I exspect.. really lost here.. All I want is a field of 5x5x5 to be displayed...

Comment: @nightslit: Well, that depends on what you _expect_. The frustum given now has an insanely wide field of view angle, so the image will look really distorted under normal viewing condifitions. Furthermore, since you don't set up some view transformation explicitely, you will get the implicit view direction of `-z` - which does match your scene well. Your rotations might actually rotate your objects into view, but it will be very crude.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to set up and "transformation explicitely" as you write it. Then, I now that for this following command glFrustum(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0); the first two value are the bottom left, and the upper right of the first window. But I don't know hot to interpret the values for near and far (what does this represent? the value of the distance between these two?) Are my values this enormous?

Comment: Well I now got my scene to be showed as hole, but it's still distorted with the following code glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)1000, (GLsizei)1000);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 20.0);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                                                       and  glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(0.0, 2.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);                                    I guess the last two parameters define the deepth that will be shows, so here 10 units?

Comment: @nightslit: the `near` and `far` parameters describe the distance (from the imaginary camera) to the near and far clipping planes. As I said in the answer, there is a viewing _volume_, and everything outside it will be not visible. Which means that stuff before the near plane is as invisible as everything behind the near plane. In your case, you havbe 20 - 1 = 19 units of depth range. Your frustum is furthermore still wierdly distorted, the first four parameters of the frustum specify a rectanlge _on the near plane_, and you still have an insanely wide FOV. Also, your apsect ratio seems wrong.

Comment: I managed to set it up correctly now, thanks for your help, it got me on the right way. It finally works with the following values: glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)1000, (GLsizei)1000); glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 20.0); glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); and glLoadIdentity(); gluLookAt(5.0, 2.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); I assume that the distortion was made by the third and fourth parameters of the glFrustum function. I removed the rotation at start on the models and replaced the view with glLookAt. By the way great explanation.